# How to search the xpath of a weblink, by only using its Link Text? Coding in R

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping, rselenium

I need to automatically lookup an href link (and find its 'xpath' or 'css selector' or ...) in order to click that link by a script in R. In the following code all of the tags change everytime I login, except the Link Text (for example "Click Me for More Info" in the following code). How can I search the xpath/css selector of this link by only using its Link Text?

```
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a name="12"></a>
<a href="/bin/WebOb/mamool.p/4/ioi/1232228/4.14.1.1.0#12">
<img width="7" border="0" align="ABSMDIDDLE" height="12" src="/WebOb/mamool.p/Frameworks/
JavaWOExtensions.framework/WebServerResources/Triangle.gif"> Click Me for More Info</a>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

`//a[text()='Click Me for More Info']`

if it works, then go extra step by

```
//a[text()='Click Me for More Info']/@href
```